# I'm attempting to get zip codes to display within zip code borders

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Several moments are happening correctly in this effort, the map is displaying as expected, the zip code boundaries are showing as expected, but I'm not able to figure how to get 5-digit zip codes to be the label within each zip code boundary.  Any help (with example code if possible) would be *greatly* appreciated!

Here's some code:

```
<html>
    <div id='mapdiv'></div>
    ...
    mapboxgl.accessToken='<token>';
var mapobj = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'mapdiv',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 20,
    zoom: 10,
    center: [-105.1613858,39.6791558]
});

<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
mapobj.on('load', function() {

    // Add ZipCode source to map
    mapobj.addSource('zipSource', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://mapbox.enterprise-boundaries-p2-v1'
    });
    mapobj.showTileBoundaries = true;

    // Add hot ZipCode layer to map
    mapobj.addLayer({
        id: 'hotZipLayer',
        type: 'fill',
        source: 'zipSource',
        'source-layer': 'boundaries_postal_2',
        paint: {
            'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
            'fill-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.01)'
        }
    });

    // Add Zip numbers symbol layer to map
    mapobj.addLayer({
        id: 'zipCodeLabels',
        type: 'symbol',
        source: 'zipSource',
        'source-layer': 'points_postal_2',
        layout: {
            'text-field': '{id}',
            'text-justify': 'center',
            'text-size' : 10
        },
        paint: {
            'text-color': 'black',
            'text-halo-color': 'white',
            'text-halo-width': 25
        }
    });
});
```

And an example data entry:

```
[
{
"geometry":
{
  "type":"Point","coordinates":[-105.0908374786377,39.707747919880916]
},
"type":"Feature",
"properties":
{
  "id":"USP280226"
},
"id":2,
"layer":
{
  "id":"zipCodeLabels",
  "type":"symbol",
  "source":"zipSource",
  "source-layer":"points_postal_2",
  "layout":
  {
    "text-field":"{id}",
    "text-justify":"center",
    "text-size":10
  },
  "paint":
  {
    "text-color":"black",
    "text-halo-color":"white",
    "text-halo-width":25
  }
}
  },...]
```

So in this case the value that would show up within the zip code boundary is "USP280226", what I would *like* to appear is "80226", so I would like to call substring(4) on that id value, but I don't see an easy way to do that for each displayed zip code on the map.

I would imagine MapBox has a way to do this properly, but I haven't been able to find it in the docs or examples.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The currently released version of Mapbox-GL-JS doesn't support any kind of functions on data. You will have to process the data offline so that it contains the labels you want to display.

(I think a forthcoming version may support this kind of function, but I'm not certain.)

EDIT The "expression" functionality is [now released](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions). Unfortunately I don't think it helps you. There's a [`concat`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-concat) function but no way to split strings that I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @steve-bennett.  The thing with processing the data offline is that I don't have the data, it's part of mapbox's "points_postal_2" source layer from the enterprise-boundaries source, I attempted to `var layer = getLayer('points_postal_2')`, but the `layer` variable is undefined when I do that :-/.  I _do_ get access to the data using the `queryRenderedFeatures()` function, but don't see how to associate each zip code with the zip code in the `zipCodeLabels` layer.  Any ideas are welcome of course as I'm not finding answers in docs.

Comment: You could maybe do something like `querySourceFeatures`, grab the data, and manipulate it in the browser, then add a new source based on that. The performance could be horrible though.

Comment: Thank you again @steve, that's what I'm thinking (likely a geoJson layer), I appreciate your thoughts here.